# Would a camshift position sensor cause my symptoms?

Tags: engine, nissan, cam-position-sensor, quest

I have a Nissan quest 2008, and I have weird symptoms. When I go to start the engine it takes about 5 seconds for it too actually turn. It sounds like it wont start but then it does.

The next symptom is the SLIP and TCS OFF light comes on , and also when I go to drive it, it feels like its in LIMP mode. I have to really press down on the gas for awhile to actually hit 40mph.

Lastly, when I put from P to R it shifts really hard. My mechanic says its a camshaft position sensor bank one problem. He checked for codes and that's what he got.

Does anyone know if this sensor would actually cause these symptoms?

Comment: so when you turn the key to the crank position it doesn't crank for a few seconds then starts cranking?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **Yes**.

According to this article, [Symptoms of a Bad or Failing Camshaft Position Sensor](https://www.yourmechanic.com/article/symptoms-of-a-bad-or-failing-camshaft-position-sensor);

> The camshaft position sensor gathers information about the vehicle’s
>   camshaft speed and sends it to the vehicle’s engine control module
>   (ECM). The ECM uses this data to determine the timing of the ignition,
>   as well as the timing of the fuel injection that the engine requires.
>   Without this information, the engine would not be able to function
>   properly.

Comment: I agree that a camshaft sensor could cause these symptoms, but there are other things which could as well.

Comment: @mongo You are correct. In this case, the the OP asked a specific question which outlined typical symptoms for a bad CPS. You are welcome to write your own answer if you believe it is something else.